# Custom menu in fragment of ActionBarActivity can't be set

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I'm using the `ActionBarActivity` and `NavigationDrawer` and wanted to set the custom menus in every `Fragment`.

Menu in fragment1:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sabd="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        sabd:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_marker"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@null"/>
</menu>
```

Menu in fragment2:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sabd="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        sabd:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_list"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@null"/>
</menu>
```

I put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `onCreate` method of both fragments.

Nevertheless, I'm using the custom drawables for the second item of the menu, I still get the same standard menu icon.

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarStyle">
</activity>
```

Style:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

So, the menu is set properly, but with the old icons. What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the

```
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

By the

```
    sabd:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```